# capitalize the field study "language arts"

Tags: capitalization

The field of study "English" should be capitalized but should "language arts" be capitalized?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - Yes

Longer answer:

"Language Arts"

It is a title for a field of study so in this context you should treat it as such.

Comment: Longer answer: in US corners of this field, common usage leans toward the abbreviation ELA, which is more prevalent at primary, middle school and secondary levels than in universities, where "English," "Literature," "Compositon," "Rhetoric" and similar designations continue to dominate.

Comment: Good info, but capitalisation is not the same as abbreviation.

Comment: Isn't this Linguistics and not Language Arts?

Answer (score 0):

Capitalization reflects importance. Here you are referring to a course name and it has its importance with regard to students, so to bring that out "Language Arts" is done.